# not loading posted back form values?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used Firebug to verify, and my callback is firing successfully. In the "Post" portion, it shows that my TextBox (rather, the HTML that was rendered for my textbox) is successfully submitting its form value (whatever was entered in the textbox). However, on the server side, the value isn't being restored into the newly created TextBox -- even though everything I'm recreating has the same ID as it originally did. Furthermore I checked the Page.Request.Form collection (see: getControlAsHtml()) and none of the things I tried returned my value. Here is the code, appreciate any help.

**Summary**

my goal is to perform a callback (currently working) and restore the value of my TextBox from the posted back form values (not working). Some (working) code has been omitted for brevity.

```
public class CreateForm : WebPart, ICallbackEventHandler
{
    public string callbackData = "";
    public DropDownList list = new DropDownList();
    public Panel p = new Panel();

    public virtual string GetCallbackResult()
    {
        return callbackData;
    }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

            //The DropDownList is created here in my real code, but was omitted
            //because it is working as expected.
            //At the moment, all the DDL does is cause a callback to occur.

        p.ID = "theForm";

        if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
        {
            MyForm MyForm = new MyForm();
            MyForm.ID = "currentForm";
            p.Controls.Add(MyForm);
        }

        Controls.Add(p);  
    }

    /*
     * The eventArgument field is parsed to get the desired command.
     * Valid commands:
     * 1) send - Indicates the user has clicked the 'send' button. 
     * 2) display - Indicates the user wants to change the form
     *              currently displayed.
     *    A drop down box is used to let the user choose the form. 
     */
    public virtual void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
                if (eventArgument.StartsWith("display"))
            {
                //always index 0 for testing. 
                callbackData = CreateFormByType(0);
                }
    }

    public string CreateFormByType(int index)
    {
        MyForm test = null;

        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                test = new MyForm();
                break;
        }

        if (test != null)
        {
            test.ID = "currentForm";
            p.Controls.Add(test);
        }

        return test != null ? test.getControlAsHtml() : null;
    }

}

public class MyForm : Control
{
    public Label label = new Label();
    public TextBox textboxForLabel = new TextBox();

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
            base.OnInit(e);

        textboxForLabel.ID = "textboxForLabel";
        label.AssociatedControlID = "textboxForLabel";
        label.Text = "textboxForLabel: ";

        this.Controls.Add(label);
        this.Controls.Add(textboxForLabel);
    }

    public virtual string getControlAsHtml()
    {
            //How come all 3 of these don't return the expected value?
        string s = Page.Request.Form[textboxForLabel.ID];
        string t = Page.Request.Form[textboxForLabel.ClientID];
        textboxForLabel.Text = (string)Page.Request.Form["textboxForLabel"];

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                this.RenderControl(textWriter);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate tags like "ASP.NET C#" in the title. They're already in the tags.

Comment: @John noted.. thanks. Now just help me answer this question and we can be best friends. :)

Comment: no, I won't. I don't have the answer, or I would have answered it.

Comment: @John relax... it was just a joke. Thanks anyway for cleaning up the thread. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So Controls.Add() isn't an innocent
>   addition to a simple collection. It
>   immediately has an impact on the
>   control being added, as it "grows up"
>   at an accelerated pace. But the steps
>   through which the control is fast
>   forwarded don't completely correspond
>   to all of the events available on the
>   page. The only events eligible for
>   this process are (in order): Init,
>   LoadViewState, Load, PreRender.

According to that article segment, which I found at [InfinitiesLoop](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/10/16/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-3_2900_.aspx), the reason that the TextBox isn't getting updated data is actually because *when a control is added to the control tree, the control catches up to the other controls in the control lifecycle. But the LoadPostData method is not eligible for this catch up process.* In other words, the data *is* available in the Request.Form collection but the LoadPostData() method is never called, since the 'MyForm' control is added from the RaiseCallbackEvent method -- which is later in the lifecycle than the LoadPostData event. So calling RegisterRequiresPostBack might work (if it forces LoadPostData to be called) but not for the reason that Priyank indicated in the comments.

I should also add that it is necessary to do the following from the Javascript code that causes the Ajax callback to occur:

```
__theFormPostData = ""; WebForm_InitCallback();
```

The reasoning behind that is that it clears the form which is not up to date and then updates it (by calling InitCallback()) before actually performing the callback request.

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = Page.Request.Form[textboxForLabel.UniqueID];
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. But it doesn't resolve the larger issue, which is "why wasn't the form data automatically restored into the TextBox, via the TextBox's LoadPostData() method"?

Comment: Your CreateFormByType() method adds completely new control 'MyForm' into the panel, everytime there is a postback. LoadPostData() restores values to original control, and not the newly added one.

Comment: You may want to add all available forms once into the panel, and depending on dropdown selection, enable/disable them instead of adding new form everytime there is a postback.

Comment: "LoadPostData() restores values to original control, and not the newly added one." How does asp.net know that the new control I added isn't the same as the original? Since the control is of the same type, contains the same data, and has the same ID. In fact, the only difference is that its added from RaiseCallbackEvent, instead of from OnInit() ...

Comment: Here is a summary of the events. LoadPostData event fires first on original controls. Your new controls are added lately when RaiseCallbackEvent event fires and so they will not be restored.

PreInit, Init, InitComplete, (if IsPostback : LoadControlState), (If IsPostback: LoadViewState), (if IsPostBack: LoadPostData), PreLoad, Load, (If IsPostback: LoadPostData "again"), (If Is Postback: Raise PostbackEvent), LoadComplete, (if IsPostback or Callback: RaiseCallbackEvent), PreRender, PreRenderComplete, SaveControlState, SaveViewstate, SaveStateComplete, Render.

Comment: Yes, but Controls that get added to the page late play 'catch up' in the control lifecycle. Also, your comment doesn't clarify why the control ID isn't available in the Page.Request.Form collection. Using the UniqueID doesn't matter since without a NamingContainer, UniqueID and ID are always the same thing.

Comment: Try implementing IPostBackDataHandler interface for MyClass control. Since, it is a parent control of your child Text control.

Comment: Textbox's UniqueID is the one which is present in Request.Form collection but your container control/custom control (MyForm) is 
the one expecting postback data handling. So to say, it's not your MyFrom's UniqueID in Request.Form collection and therefore its LoadPostData won't get called (Page runs FindControl with  the uniqueid and if a control is found, tries to cast it to IPostBackDataHandler)

Comment: There's a mechanism to ensure that LoadPostData is called despite that control's UniqueID is not present in post data collection (Request.Form). The control needs to of course still implement IPostBackDataHandler interface and register itself to the Page to require postback data handling. This happens by calling Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack method. And a good place for it is in overridden OnPreRender method. So it could look like this

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    if(Page != null)
        Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack(this);
}

Comment: Priyank, thanks for all your explanations. But I'm still confused. Why is the MyForm expecting postback data handling? I only care about the TextBox (which is a child control of MyForm) restoring its state, not MyForm itself. Does MyForm have to implement IPostBackDataHandler in order for its child controls to Load their post data? That wouldn't make much sense and I haven't seen any information to that effect...

Comment: During a callback, the HttpContext of the page is invalid, so you can't use the Request/Response properties of System.Web.UI.Page. Refer this http://forums.asp.net/t/1271615.aspx

Comment: In this case, your best bet is to send data through custom formatted string as eventArgument to Raisecallbackevent and/or as querystring.

Comment: "During a callback, the HttpContext of the page is invalid, so you can't use the Request/Response properties of System.Web.UI.Page." That is simply not true. I printed out Page.Request.Form.AllKeys on my callback, and the collection was not null; in fact, it had a number of entries, including my TextBox. Furthermore on an ICallbackEventHandler callback most of the Page lifecycle is executed, so what would make you think Request.Form is unavailable?

Comment: KyleM, collection is there but values are not valid. Try puting a button next to the textbox and clicking on it. Button does post back. When you debug the Page.Request.Form[], they have values. Callback and postback, both have same params, just values are not valid for callback where postback has valid values. try it. I did on my side.

Comment: Actually callback does have the correct, valid values. If I print out the (key, value) pairs from the Request.Form collection, at the top of the RaiseCallbackEvent method, the value that I entered in my TextBox DOES show up as one of the (key, value) pairs. In any case I figured out what is going on and will be posting the answer shortly.